# Corona SQLIte : Checking if a value exists or not

Tags: sqlite, lua, coronasdk

I would like to check if a value can be returned or not by my SQL request:

```
Search_IDItem = "SELECT * FROM giftshop WHERE id ="..item_id..""
            for row_2 in db:nrows(Search_IDItem) do (..)

CheckInventory = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE code ="..row_2.code..""
if CheckInventory ~= nil then
    print(row_2.code)
    updateItemsCode(row_2.code, "inventory", "qtyoninventory", row_2.qtyoninventory+1)
else
    insertInventory(2,row_2.code, row_2.name, row_2.src, row_2.desc, "no",row_2.qtyoninventory,row_2.price,row_2.usetxt)
end
```

The error is:

> near "=": syntax error

Basicly, I would like to know if the value exist, I'll only update the field "quantity", if not, I will create the new item.

Unfortunately, it doesn't work! Is there any advice or solution?

Comment: row_2.code is taken from a previous request. In fact, when i display "row_2.code" is gave me the right "value". But cannot compare it ! The code is an alphanumeric (item01, item02, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Syntax error is a result of misunderstanding of your query by the SQL.
One of the most often reasons is incorrect string insertion. So I suppose that row_xx.code is a string
To solve the problem you should "quote" row_xx.code by ' symbol like this:

```
CheckInventory = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE code ='"..row_2.code.."'"
```

**Update** 
To solve the second part of the problem and figure out if value exists I suggest following
In old good plain Java when I get SQLite Cursor I may check if it has rows at all like this:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
   // it has at least one value
else
   // it hasn't values at all
```

Sure there is similar thing for Corona

You also may use following approach to update record (creating if not exists):

```
// create record IF NOT EXISTS:
String createNonExistentRec = "Insert or ignore into "...// insert key/unique values
db.execSQL(createNonExistentRec, ...);

// update values:
String updateQuery = "..."
...
```

Comment: It's a first step in resolving my problem ! But what will happened if the SQL request has "no result" ? I mean, the second part of my "condition" wont be executed.

Comment: Thank u for the help. It's pretty difficult for me as i don't know Java

Comment: You don't have to know Java - please look at the idea. 1) There is some way to find out are there any values fetched by SELECT query. 2) INSERT OR IGNORE query followed by UPDATE query may also help you -  it's straightforward and efficient

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
for x in db:urows "select count(*) from inventory" do 
  if x>0 then -- The inventory is empty
    for w in db:urows("SELECT count (*) FROM inventory WHERE code ='"..row_2.code.."'") do
       --The item is already in the inventory
       if w > 0 then 
           CheckInventory = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE code ='"..row_2.code.."'"
                   for row_4 in db:nrows(CheckInventory) do
                       updateItemsCode(row_4.code, "inventory", "qtyoninventory", row_4.qtyoninventory+1)
                   end
       else
       --The item is not in the inventory, so we add it! 
            for maxid in db:urows("SELECT MAX(id) FROM inventory") do
                   insertInventory(maxid+1,row_2.code, row_2.name, row_2.src, row_2.desc, "no",1,row_2.price,row_2.usetxt)
             end
       end
    end
 else
    insertInventory(1,row_2.code, row_2.name, row_2.src, row_2.desc, "no",1,row_2.price,row_2.usetxt)
 end
end
```